# Facebook share image method on Intel XDK

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, intel-xdk

i implemented the intel.xdk.facebook.showNewsFeedDialog method on my app, everything works as expected, link, image thumbnail and description are posted to my wall.
I want to know if there's a intel api for my app share works like instagram do, sharing a full image on my wall with some text, like user posted a normal photo and text to friends.
Any help will be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method within the Intel XDK API Facebook* object that allows you to post images.

[Parse](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#fbusers) has a set of helpful step-by-step instructions for integrating Facebook users/APIs into your app.